# Call function, which uses hooks, from inside react-navigation custom header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

I have a screen written with React Hooks.
On the screen I have a custom button in react-navigation header. By press on the button I need to call function `updateUser` which uses values from state (for example `userName`).

So I pass `updateUser` function to the header with `navigation.setParams` function.
In the header I call `updateUser` from `navigation.state.params`.

On the first press - the `userName` value is correct. But if I then will change value `userName` from inside the component - when I press the button, the value inside function remains unchanged.

Here is example of code:

```
const ProfileScreen = ({navigation}) => {
 const [userName, setUserName] = useState('John');

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
      updateUser,
    });
  }, [])

  const updateUser = () => {
    console.log('userName', userName);
  }

  return (...)
};
ProfileScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  headerRight: () => {
    const {params = {}} = navigation.state;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.updateUser()}>
        <Text>Update user</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  },
});
```

I assume that happens because header is outside of a component scope and doesn't get updated state value. Also React has a rule which states to not call hooks outside of React functions.

Is there any proper way to solve it? If not, what is the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

My **workaround #1** is to use one more `useState` which keeps tracking on whether Update button was pressed.

So in header when the button is pressed we set `isUpdateButtonPressed` to true. Then in the component we watch for that change and if it is changed - we call `updateUser`. This way the state is correct inside of `updateUser` function.

```
const ProfileScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('John');
  const [isUpdateButtonPressed, setIsUpdateButtonPressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
      setIsUpdateButtonPressed,
    });
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUpdateButtonPressed) {
      updateUser();
      setIsUpdateButtonPressed(false);
    }
  }, [isUpdateButtonPressed]);

  const updateUser = () => {
    console.log('userName', userName);
  }
};
ProfileScreen.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  headerRight: () => {
    const {params = {}} = navigation.state;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.setIsUpdateButtonPressed(true)}>
        <Text>Update user</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  },
});
```

My **workaround #2** was to use `useEffect` to watch for all variables used in `updateUser` function and call `navigation.setParams` with updated `updateUser` function every time those variables change:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
      updateUser,
    });
  }, [userName])
```

Though solution #2 is a bit cleaner in code, personally I prefer solution #1 as the second one may lead to not obvious bugs in case we miss to add some variable, which is used in `updateUser` function, to useEffect array.